# mysql dosen't select all when using the SELECT function

Tags: php, mysql

My code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `sw1`, `sw2`, `sw3`, `sw4`, `fb1`, `fb2`, `fb3`, `fb4`, `bew1`, `bew2`, `bew3`, `bew4` FROM `reg` WHERE `id` = ".$id." ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        foreach($row as $x => $x_value) {
             echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
             echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

There is some data in `sw2` but it isn't shown.
When I tryed to UPDATE data the data in the db wasn't changed.
`$id` is right.
other data from the table could be read.

Comment: It's not selecting all columns or all rows? How many records with `$id` are there?

Comment: echo your query and run it on mysql...

Comment: by leaving  ".$id." and first and last double qoute remove all other quote

Comment: there is one row with 12 rows and ther isn't all Data, but ther is some

Comment: You are limiting your result set to 30 records.  Could this be the reason why you are not seeing all data?  Could you try running the query standalone in MySQL to see what you get?

Comment: One row with 12 columns of data?

Comment: yes (chris) ther are only 20 records in the whole table

Comment: Okay, than no reason for the `while(` nor the `limit`. You will only be getting one record because of the where. If you want all columns returned just use the `*` in the select no need to list all columns. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM \`reg\` WHERE \`id\` = $id";`

Comment: Chris you are right I don't need the Limit, because `$id` is autoincreasing

Comment: but with `*` the Problem isn't solved

Comment: What happens with `*`?

Comment: it is the same as before with more colums

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76827/discussion-between-chris85-and-jakob-leifhelm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE `id` = ".$id." ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your query with echo.
same trouble follows try changing **Where 'id' = "$id"** 
to **Where 'id' like "$id"**

Comment: but phpmyadmin uses ´id´ = 10 for example

Comment: when you fetch the data from **MYSQL** using **PHP** it will always result you in string. and if you want to manage that data to suppose int you can try **$id = (int) $row['userid'];**

Answer (score 0):

You dont need quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT sw1, sw2, sw3, sw4, fb1, fb2, fb3, fb4, 
bew1, bew2, bew3, bew4 
FROM reg WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: The quotes don't harm. Deleting them does not improve the SQL.

Comment: Maybe not, but it will definitely save you some time.